# align both left and right (justify) of tabularx environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tabularx

I am using `tabularx` package and environment to list contents in the text.

The codes are as follows.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}
\linespread{1.05}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\par a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
\vspace{10pt} \par
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}lX}
    \vspace{10pt} No. 1. & a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a  \\
    \vspace{10pt} No. 2. & a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a  \\
    \vspace{10pt} No. 3. & a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a  \\
\end{tabularx}
\par a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
\end{document}
```

The output is as follows.

[image]

It can be seen that the listed contexts are only left aligned with the normal text, but not right aligned with the normal text.

Does anyone know how to solve this, or are there other better packages or environments to achieve this performance?

Comment: `{@{}lX@{}}` to remove the right hand padding, just as you had on the left

Answer (score 0):

You might use

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}lX@{}}
```

but I believe you can do better with `enumitem`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\linespread{1.05}

\begin{document}

a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a 
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a 
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a 
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a 
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a 
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a 
a a a a a a a a a a a a a
\begin{enumerate}[
  leftmargin=3.5em,
  labelwidth=3.5em,
  labelsep=0pt,
  align=left,
  label=No.\ \arabic*.]
\item a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
      a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
      a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
\item a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
      a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
      a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
\item a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
      a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
      a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
\end{enumerate}
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a 
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a 
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a 
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a 
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a 
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a 
a a a a a a a a a a a a a

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note `No.\ \arabic*.` with backslash-space, so the period is not interpreted as sentence ending.